# How to instantiate an array of Prefabs in C# Script

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

Sorry if this sounds quite primitive, I am new to Unity. I am trying to instantiate an array of prefabs, but it doesn't seem to appear when I run the game. Firstly I created my block prefabs, then I created an empty game object and added the following script to the empty object.

```
public class BlocksTestScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] blockPrefabs;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        blockPrefabs = new GameObject[7];
        blockPrefabs = Resources.LoadAll ("/Prefab/BlockPrefabs") as GameObject[];

                for (int i = 0; i < blockPrefabs.Length; i++) {
        GameObject myPrefabs = Instantiate(blockPrefabs[i], blockPrefabs[i].transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }

    }

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Assets/Resources/Scripts/BlockTestScript.cs(14,28): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

How can I resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**

After looping through to instantiate the prefabs I now get the following error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
BlocksTestScript.Start () (at Assets/Resources/Scripts/BlocksTestScript.cs:15)
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to instantiate an entire array of GameObjects as a single GameObject. First things first, I would suggest looping through the array and instantiating one at a time.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo I just updated the question

Comment: `blockPrefabs` is null after `Resources.LoadAll ("/Prefab/BlockPrefabs") as GameObject[];` so it's wrong. Also, use `Instantiate(blockPrefabs[i]); ` instead of all this. If you have 7 prefabs, why don't you just assign them in the inspector? Above code is a bad practice cause if you move them to another folder in the future, you'll have a bad day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place look at your instantiation code: it makes no sense. You're assigning a `GameObject myPrefabs` (why the name `myPrefab`? It's not a prefab after you instantiate it; and why the `s`? every one your instances is ONE instance) but as soon as you go out of the `for` loop's scope, you've already lost that reference. You need to set up an empty array like this in your class:

`GameObject blocks[] = new GameObject[7];`

and then do

```
for (int i = 0; i < blockPrefabs.Length; i++)
    blocks[i] = Instantiate(blockPrefabs[i]) as GameObject;
```

...now you will maintain the references to each `block` in that array, and can work with these later.

Secondly I'm not sure why you'd want to complicate things by using `Resources.Load` on your prefabs. Just drag your individual prefabs from the Project or Hierarchy views into the inspector listing for `public GameObject[] blockPrefabs` on your `BlocksTestScript` (after setting that array's size to 7 or whatever there in the inspector). Then you can remove the first 2 lines in your `Start()`.

```
public class BlocksTestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] blockPrefabs; //size gets set in inspector! drag prefabs in there!
    public GameObject[] blocks;

    void Start ()
    {   
        blocks = new GameObject[blockPrefabs.Length]; //makes sure they match length
        for (int i = 0; i < blockPrefabs.Length; i++)
        {
             blocks[i] = Instantiate(blockPrefabs[i]) as GameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Precisely, what I need. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.